# Поиск по повторам в txt-файле разрастается до немыслимых масштабов

Tags: php, foreach

Имеется txt-файл следующего вида (в нем до 1000 строк):

```
0 => 112 15 мкр, 4/5, 4 700 000. Tel1
1 => 112 15 мкр, 4/5, 4 800 000. Tel1
2 => 112 14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2 4 000 000. Tel2
3 => 112 14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2, 4 000 000. Tel2
4 => 112 15 мкр, 2/5. Tel3
5 => 112 15 мкр, 3/5, 5 000 000 тг. Tel4
6 => 112 15 мкр, 4/5, 5 000 000. Tel1
7 => 112 15 мкр, 4/5, 6 800 000. Tel1
8 => 112 горняков 53, 3/4, не угол, варианты. Tel5
9 => 112 горняков 53, 3/4, не угол. Tel5
10 => 112 Горького 47, 1/4, счетчик, пл. окна, частично мебель, 4 500 000. Tel6
11 => 112 Горького 47, 1/4, хор. ремонт, ч/мебл, 4 500 000. Tel6
12 => 112 Достык, 1/4, кондиционер и кух/гарнитур. Tel7
13 => 112 Железорудная, пл/окна, ремонт, 2 300 000. Tel8
```

Нужно вывести на экран только повторы для каждой строки в файле, если они есть. Строки считаются одинаковыми, если 1) телефон в конце строк один и тот же и 2) длина всех строк одинаковая (без учета регистра, знаков препинания и пробелов, только буквы и цифры).
Итак, берем первую строку '0=>...', пробежались циклом по всем строкам начиная с '1=>...', вывели на экран. Затем берем вторую строку '1=>' пробежались циклом по всем строкам начиная с '2=>...'. То есть, каждую n-строку сравниваем со строками, начиная с n+1-строкой и так до конца документа (именно это я прописал в if).

```
$arr = file($txt);
foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
    foreach($arr as $nkey=>$nitem){
       if($key != $nkey && $key < $nkey){
          echo '<p>' . $key . ': ' . $arr[$key] . '<p><br>';
          echo '<p>' . $nkey . ': ' . $arr[$nkey] . '<p><br><br>';
       }
    }
}
```

Это работает нормально, если всего две одинаковые строки. А теперь представьте, если их 10 штук идущих друг за другом в документе... На первом шаге цикла искомая строка выведется с 9 найденными повторами (здесь порядок). Но ведь потом мы продолжаем искать повторы для следующей строки. И выходит, что на втором шаге цикла выводится 2 строка, которую мы видели на первом шаге, и 8 найденных повторов (которые мы тоже видели на первом шаге). Теперь иллюстрация, как это выглядит у меня на основе строк, которые показал в начале:

```
__112   15 мкр, 4/5, 4 700 000. Tel1__ (строка "0=>..." и ее повторы, здесь порядок)
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 4 800 000. Tel1
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 5 000 000. Tel1
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 6 800 000. Tel1

__112   15 мкр, 4/5, 4 800 000. Tel1__ (не должно выводиться, дублирование)
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 5 000 000. Tel1
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 6 800 000. Tel1

__112   15 мкр, 4/5, 5 000 000. Tel1__ (не должно выводиться, дублирование)
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 6 800 000. Tel1


__112   14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2 4 000 000. Tel2__
112 14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2, 4 000 000. Tel2

__112   горняков 53, 3/4, не угол, варианты. Tel5__
112 горняков 53, 3/4, не угол. Tel5

__112   Горького 47, 1/4, счетчик, пл. окна, частично мебель, 4 500 000. Tel6__
112 Горького 47, 1/4, хор. ремонт, ч/мебл, 4 500 000. Tel6
```

***Теперь как должно быть:***

```
__112   15 мкр, 4/5, 4 700 000. Tel1__
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 4 800 000. Tel1
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 5 000 000. Tel1
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 6 800 000. Tel1

__112   14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2 4 000 000. Tel2__
112 14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2, 4 000 000. Tel2

__112   горняков 53, 3/4, не угол. Tel5__
112 горняков 53, 3/4, не угол. Tel5

__112   Горького 47, 1/4, счетчик, пл. окна, частично мебель, 4 500 000. Tel6__
112 Горького 47, 1/4, хор. ремонт, ч/мебл, 4 500 000. Tel6
```

Прошу прощения за размытые объяснения. Как не выводить на экран десять раз одно и то же? Спасибо!

Comment: вложенный цикл от начальной позиции уж точно не нужен, он должен с текущей + 1 начинаться. вам найти то надо только повторяющиеся строки, и сколько раз они там встречаются?

Comment: приведите пример входного файла (20 строк, например) и ожидаемого результата

Comment: У тебя цикл в цикле одного и того-же массива причем даже если этот код назвать решением всех "проблем" то один цикл нихрена не контролирует другой))) Если бы был импровизированный кусок данных (файл) мы бы помогли бы тебе решить проблему в один цикл и все остальные болячки бы исчезли))

Comment: @teran, привел пример: в самом вопросе показал, как выглядит txt-файл

Comment: @user3126867, подправил основной вопрос. Там, где "Tel1" - это считается повторяющаяся строка (разница 1-2 символа), но сама длина строки не меняется

Comment: Особо понятнее не стало. Так строки идентичные или нет?

Comment: @MBo, вот смотрите. Там, где Tel1 - это один и тот же номер телефона. Но сами строки отличаются только одним символом: в первой строке "4 700 000", во второй - "4 800 000", еще ниже вместо "4 700 000" стоит "5 000 000". Строки считаются идентичными, если tel в конце строки один и тот же и если длина строк одинаковая. Поиск повторов по первой строке - строки 2, 7, 8. Повторы для второй строки - строки 7, 8. Но дубликаты для второй строки мы уже видели среди дубликатов для 1-ой строки. Прошу прощения за туманные объяснения, я старался...

Comment: Да, действительно туманные. Вам нужно чётко сформулировать критерий группировки строк и по сути определить функцию вроде "the_same_string". Подозреваю, что только по номеру телефона группировать нельзя - один человек (или агенство) может дать несколько объявлений. Кроме того, нужна нормализация телефонных номеров (начало с +7 или 8, скобки, дефисы)

Comment: Сейчас дополню вопрос

Comment: Дополнил ответ  :)

Comment: @forever_young, посмотрите мой ответ ниже. Он делает, на мой взгляд то, что вы просите. Единственное, у меня есть вопросы по входным данным/выходным. Например - по вашему условию, как я его понял, строки с  ` ... Горького 47 ...` считаются дублями, но у них ведь разная итоговая длина?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

0) На данном этапе проще всего **удалять** использованные строки из массива.

---

1) array_unique() - если повторы на самом деле не нужны

2) отсортировать массив - дальше, думаю, всё понятно

3) каждую строку складывать в hashmap как ключ, если номера нужны - они добавляются в значение-список, если только количество повторов - целочисленное значение инкрементировать каждый раз

Comment: Это будет костыль))

Comment: Попробую насчет удаления использованных...

Answer (score 1):

Инициализация результирующего массива `$h` за один проход, по элементам входного массива.

Результирующий массив позволяет:

- извлечь по хешу строки все номера индексов значений исходного массива с таким же хешем;
- по индексу значения исходного массива получить дубли;

## Обновлено

```
<?php
//$arr = file($txt);
$arr = [
    '112 15 мкр, 4/5, 4 700 000. Tel1',
    '112 15 мкр, 4/5, 4 800 000. Tel1',
    '112 14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2 4 000 000. Tel2',
    '112 14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2, 4 000 000. Tel2',
    '112 15 мкр, 2/5. Tel3',
    '112 15 мкр, 3/5, 5 000 000 тг. Tel4',
    '112 15 мкр, 4/5, 5 000 000. Tel1',
    '112 15 мкр, 4/5, 6 800 000. Tel1',
    '112 горняков 53, 3/4, не угол, варианты. Tel5',
    '112 горняков 53, 3/4, не угол. Tel5',
    '112 Горького 47, 1/4, счетчик, пл. окна, частично мебель, 4 500 000. Tel6',
    '112 Горького 47, 1/4, хор. ремонт, ч/мебл, 4 500 000. Tel6',
    '112 Достык, 1/4, кондиционер и кух/гарнитур. Tel7',
    '112 Железорудная, пл/окна, ремонт, 2 300 000. Tel8'
];

function hashed($s)
{
    // хешируем строку, предварительно очищая от небуквенных и нецифровых знаков
    return md5(mb_strlen(preg_replace('/[^\p{L}|\p{Nd}]/u', '', $s)));
}

$h = [
    'known' => [],
    'dup' => []
];

foreach ($arr as $num => $str) {
    $hash = hashed($str);
    $h['dup'][$num] = [];
    if (!isset($h['known'][$hash])) {
        $h['known'][$hash] = [$num];
    } else {
        $h['known'][$hash][] = $num;
        foreach ($h['known'][$hash] as $dnum) {
            if ($dnum === $num) {
                continue;
            }
            $h['dup'][$dnum][] = $num;
            $h['dup'][$num][] = $dnum;
        }
    }
}


foreach ($h['known'] as $dups) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($dups); $i++) {
        echo ($i==0? "__": "") . $arr[$dups[$i]] . ($i==0? "__": "") . "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
/*// получить дубли для 2 строки
var_dump($h['dup'][1]); // их нет - массив []

// получить дубли для 1 строки
var_dump($h['dup'][0]); // есть, массив [3, 4]

// получить дубли для 4 строки
var_dump($h['dup'][3]); // есть, массив [0, 4]

// получить дубли для строки 'a a a  a'
$str = 'a a a  a';
var_dump($h['known'][hashed($str)]); //// есть, массив [0, 3, 4]
*/
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2729b0369a536a94db0fa992c74b42c7442d8486)

Результат:

```
__112 15 мкр, 4/5, 4 700 000. Tel1__
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 4 800 000. Tel1
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 5 000 000. Tel1
112 15 мкр, 4/5, 6 800 000. Tel1

__112 14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2 4 000 000. Tel2__
112 14 мкр, Лада, 2/5, 45,3 м2, 4 000 000. Tel2

__112 15 мкр, 2/5. Tel3__

__112 15 мкр, 3/5, 5 000 000 тг. Tel4__

__112 горняков 53, 3/4, не угол, варианты. Tel5__

__112 горняков 53, 3/4, не угол. Tel5__

__112 Горького 47, 1/4, счетчик, пл. окна, частично мебель, 4 500 000. Tel6__

__112 Горького 47, 1/4, хор. ремонт, ч/мебл, 4 500 000. Tel6__

__112 Достык, 1/4, кондиционер и кух/гарнитур. Tel7__
112 Железорудная, пл/окна, ремонт, 2 300 000. Tel8
```

Answer (score 0):

Если исходный файл - `$txt`, простейшее решение учета повторов такое:

```
var_dump(array_count_values(file($txt)));
```

Comment: Такое не пойдет: "одинаковость" строки определяется не конкретными символами, а длиной строки. Например, "4 700 000" и "4800000" в моем случае это одинаковые строки, если в конце строки стоит один и тот же телефон.. Знаки препинания и пробелы удаляются, и строки сравниваются.

Comment: @forever_young, напишите в исходном сообщении примерно так: входные данные: ... должно получиться так: ... Иначе не всем участникам будет понятно что вы хотите получить без тщательного вчитывания.

Comment: написал. Надеюсь, так лучше)